# splice() wrong component in data array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Let's say I have a form, and can add or remove a column by a click.

I use `v-for` to render the vue components, when I try to use `splice()` to delete a specific component, it always delete the last component in the array.

I can't figure out what I did wrong here, any hint will be very appreciated.

Here is a part of my code:
the problem is occured at `removePerson` method.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
<div class="form-container">
    <template>
        <div v-for="(child, key) in otherPersonArray" :key="key" class="form-container">
            <button @click="removePerson(key)" class="close">X</button>
            <component :is="child"></component>
        </div>
    </template>
    <button @click="addPerson" >+ Add Person</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import otherPerson from './OtherPerson';

export default {
    components: {
        otherPerson
    },
    data() {
        return {
            otherPersonArray: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addPerson() {
            if (this.otherPersonArray.length <= 10) {
                this.otherPersonArray.push(otherPerson);
            }
        },
        removePerson(key) {
            this.otherPersonArray.splice(key, 1);
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

For example, when I try to delete the component which input value is 1, it delete the component which input value is 2.

**otherPerson** component

```
<template>
<div class="form-container">
    <div class="person">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
                <label for="inventor-last-name">Lastname of Person *</label>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input v-model="lastName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            lastName: '',
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you console.log(key) in your removePerson function to check what you getting in it?

Comment: Hi @SurjeetBhadauriya, I checked the `console.log`, I got `0` when I tried to deleted the first component, but it deleted the second one...

Comment: @syltai can you please put your array structure here before going to delete

Comment: I'm not should what array structure means, but the array would be: `[otherPerson, otherPerson, otherPerson]`, after clicking three times add button. The `otherPerson` is vue component

Comment: @syltai  can you try what I suggested in answer and let me know, its working or not?

Comment: @syltai If you are getting proper index value then it should remove the respective one only. Check example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5kvvd5?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Hi @SurjeetBhadauriya yes, but what's in my array is vue component, not the `object` data in your link.

Comment: @syltai I have updated it with component, still working. Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5kvvd5?file=src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score -1):

there are couple of ways to achieve this but for now can you try these:

```
removePerson(key) {
            this.otherPersonArray = this.otherPersonArray.filter(person => {
                 return person.key === key;
             })
        }
```

OR

```
const index = this.otherPersonArray.indexOf(ele by key); // get index by key person key
if (index > -1) {
  this.otherPersonArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

What I am understanding key is index here then you should follow this:

```
 var filtered = this.otherPersonArray.filter(function(value, index){ 
    return index !== key;
});
```

let me know if still it not working for you?

Here is example :

[image]

Comment: Hi @SandeepTiwari, I tried the two of these, the first one delete the all components, the second one still delete the last component when I tried to delete the first.

Comment: @sytai  can you log the predicate and see what its returning, if not can you share your filled array here I will try it at my end and let you know what is going wrong

Comment: Hi @SandeppTiwari, thanks fort the third code, I'm not sure if I did wrong, it return `filtered is not defined`.

Comment: @syltai  can you give me your filled array?

Comment: I found a mistake in my code, and I use the third code successfully, it change the `otherPersonArray`, but it still deleted the last one instead of the specific one.

Comment: @syltai it means  predicate is getting true for last one, this way only  filter works, see I am going to put example in my answer only

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Tiwari, I tried the `filter` method, but it perform the same, still can't delete the specific one.

Comment: @syltai could you share your filled array of component so that I can try it my end, as you can see in example screen its working as per your requirement

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Tiwari, I have edit the post. You can see the there is an input holds the last name of person. For example, when I try to delete the component which input value is `1`, it delete the component which input value is `2`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter`

```
removePerson(key) { 
  this.otherPerson = this.otherPersonArray.filter((x, i) => i !== key);
}
```